# AngularJS: Conditional Statements not working in angular JS method of controller

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.menu-disabled-true {
color: gray;
}
.menu-disabled-false {
color: red;
}

.menu-disabled-green {
color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function DeathrayMenuController($scope) {
$scope.isDisabled = false;
$scope.stun = function() {
// stun the target, then disable menu to allow regeneration
if($scope.isDisabled == 'false'){
    $scope.isDisabled = 'true';
}else if($scope.isDisabled == 'true'){
       $scope.isDisabled = 'green';
}
};
}
</script>
<div ng-controller='DeathrayMenuController'>
<ul>
<li class='menu-disabled-{{isDisabled}}' ng-click='stun()'>Stun</li>
</ul>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Now, whenever I click on the **Stun** `<li>` then i expect it to change color as per method inside the controller.

Can Someone help me in understanding why it isnt working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing string value and boolean  value.
Change the declaration to **'false'** (string)

```
$scope.isDisabled = 'false';
$scope.stun = function() {
// stun the target, then disable menu to allow regeneration
if($scope.isDisabled == 'false'){
    $scope.isDisabled = 'true';
}else if($scope.isDisabled == 'true'){
       $scope.isDisabled = 'green';
}
};
```

Comment: @CodingNinja Your were absoluetly correct.. but still on correcting it, I get a single transition from Red to grey. but on reclicking I do not get green

Comment: @Padyster 1st click: `false => true`, 2nd click: `true => green`, 3rd click: `neither false nor true, so no condition is met`

Comment: @Padyster you didnt complete the if else block
if you want to have change colours in a cyclic order then,

if($scope.isDisabled == 'false'){
    $scope.isDisabled = 'true';
}else if($scope.isDisabled == 'true'){
       $scope.isDisabled = 'green';
}else if($scope.isDisabled == 'green'){
       $scope.isDisabled = 'false';
}

Comment: @CodingNinja Yes You R right, I must complete the cycle.... Thanks for the detail analysis and resolutions

Answer (score 1):

If you use the simple HTML `class` attribute angular evaluates the expression only once (or never).

You have to use [`ng-class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass). Something like this:

```
<li ng-class="{'menu-disabled-green': isDisabled == true, 
'menu-disabled-true': isDisabled == false}" >Stun</li>
```

From the docs:

> Expression to eval. The result of the evaluation can be a string
>   representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class
>   names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the
>   properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the
>   element.

Comment: *If you use the simple HTML class attribute angular evaluates the expression only once (or never).* - that's not true at all. The expression will continuously be evaluated just like every other expression. http://jsbin.com/aTIjeHU/2/